# Proper way to define Airflow DAG task ordering

Tags: airflow

I have a rather long set of tasks in a DAG and each has quite a long `task_id`, the details are all relevant, and the naming can't be shortened.
Currently I have written it like:

```
a_very_long_long_named_task_1 >> a_very_long_long_named_task_2 >> a_very_long_long_named_task_3 >> a_very_long_long_named_task_4 >> a_very_long_long_named_task_5
```

In other DAGs, I have seen this be split into multiple lines, albeit with duplication:

```
a_very_long_long_named_task_1 >> a_very_long_long_named_task_2
a_very_long_long_named_task_2 >> a_very_long_long_named_task_3
a_very_long_long_named_task_3 >> a_very_long_long_named_task_4
a_very_long_long_named_task_4 >> a_very_long_long_named_task_5
```

Which is recommended? Is there a best practice, or perhaps another better way to define task ordering?

Answer (score 4):

- You can keep adding your tasks to `python` `list` (or `dict` / something similar) as and when you create (instantiate) them
- Then at the end you can *wire* them up programmatically

*Note that the snippet is untested*

```py
from typing import List
from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator

my_tasks: List[BaseOperator] = [
    a_very_long_long_named_task_1,
    a_very_long_long_named_task_2,
    a_very_long_long_named_task_3, 
    a_very_long_long_named_task_4, 
    a_very_long_long_named_task_5
]

..

# define a utility method to set dependencies b/w tasks
def wire_tasks(my_tasks: List[BaseOperator]) -> None:
    """
    A utility method that accepts a list of tasks and links them up
    :param my_tasks: List of tasks (operator instances)
    :type my_tasks: List[BaseOperator]
    :return None
    """
    for i in range(1, len(my_tasks)):
        # this is equivalent to my_tasks[i - 1].set_upstream(my_tasks[i])
        my_tasks[i - 1] >> my_tasks[i]

# call the utility method to wire the tasks
wire_tasks(my_tasks=my_tasks)
```